# Cloud functions for firebase - Function structure with several promises being returned

Tags: javascript, firebase, firebase-realtime-database, google-cloud-functions

Need to know if my function is well structured and returning promises correctly. I am handling new and deleted data with a main conditional if statement. If data exists I am performing a database set and returning a promise `return ProposalsRef.child(recipient).set`. If data does not exists I return `return ProposalsRef.once('value')...`. Whenever the function is triggered it will return only one promise (this way it should never timeout). Also I am implementing an `else{return null;}` at the end just to avoid timeouts (not sure if this is a good practice)

```
exports.ObserveJobs = functions.database.ref("/jobs/{jobid}").onWrite((event) => {
    const jobid = event.params.jobid;
    if (event.data.exists() && !event.data.previous.exists()) {
        const recipient = event.data.child("recipient").val();
        if (recipient !== null) {
            let ProposalsRef = admin.database().ref(`proposals/${jobid}`);
            return ProposalsRef.child(recipient).set({
                budget: event.data.child("budget").val(),
                description: event.data.child("description").val(),
                ischat: false,
                isinvitation: true,
                timing: event.data.child("timing").val(),
            });
        };
    } else if (!event.data.exists() && event.data.previous.exists()) {
        let ProposalsRef = admin.database().ref(`proposals/${jobid}`);
        return ProposalsRef.once('value').then(snapshot => {
            if (snapshot.hasChildren()) {
                const updates = {};
                snapshot.forEach(function(child) {
                    updates[child.key] = null;
                });
                return ProposalsRef.update(updates);
            }
        });
    }else{
      return null;
    };
});
```

I would also like to know, let's say I would have to perform several database operations instead of one. See example bellow:

```
return contractRef.once('value').then(snapshot => {
    let client = snapshot.child("contractor").val();
    let freelancer = snapshot.child("talent").val();
    const clientRef = admin.database().ref(`users/${client}`);
    const freelancerRef = admin.database().ref(`users/${freelancer}`);
    clientRef.child("/account/jobcount").transaction(current => {
        return (current || 0) + 1;
    });
    freelancerRef.child("/account/jobcount").transaction(current => {
        return (current || 0) + 1;
    });
    clientRef.child("/notifications").push({
      timestamp: admin.database.ServerValue.TIMESTAMP,
      key: contractid,
      type: 4
    });
    freelancerRef.child("/notifications").push({
      timestamp: admin.database.ServerValue.TIMESTAMP,
      key: contractid,
      type: 4
    });
});
```

I am returning only `return contractRef...` promise, should promises within contractRef be returned as well (freelancerRef, clientRef)? if so, should I create an array of promises and then `return Promise.all(arrayOfProimises);` or I can return the promises individually `return freelancerRef.child("/notifications").push({...`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`Promise.all([...])` will create a single promise that is fulfilled only when all the other individual promises are fulfilled.  This is what you should return from `then` (which will should then be returned by the entire function) to make sure it waits for all the work to complete before cleaning up.  You won't be able to return individual promises separately.